# Azure App Service - Is there a limit of free ssl certificates for an app?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-appservice

I've found several statements online stating that you can have 250-500 custom domains on a single app service (assuming a basic or higher plan). I wonder if anyone knows - can you use a free ssl certificate for each custom domain (no wildcard, just simple [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com))?

I found this:

[https://azure.github.io/AppService/2017/07/24/FAQ-SSL-certificates-for-Web-Apps-and-App-Service-Certificates.html#:~:text=App%20Service%20Certificates%20has%20a,types%20the%20limit%20is%203](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2017/07/24/FAQ-SSL-certificates-for-Web-Apps-and-App-Service-Certificates.html#:%7E:text=App%20Service%20Certificates%20has%20a,types%20the%20limit%20is%203).

Which states that you get 10 certificates - but I could be (and hope I am) reading that wrong or misunderstanding. Do you get 10 certs, or can you get 1 cert for each custom domain (e.g. 200 custom domains = the possibility of 200 free certs)?

Answer (score 1):

What you refer as free ssl certificate is called App Service Managed Certification that is currently in preview.  [Looking at the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits), this service has no limits yet listed. App Service Certificates have a limit of 10 **per subscription** that can be increased via a support request to a maximum limit of 200.  The managed ones may have the same limits or Microsoft may not have decided on a limit since the service is still in preview but to be sure, I'd suggest that you open a support ticket to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

When you usges free subscriptoins there will be limit for the same.
But you can simply raise a rquest to increase the same with azure support or just
upgrade your plan from free to Pay As You Go.

Thanks,
SantoshH